# Unconditionally fail unit test

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Is there a shorthand in jasmine equivalent to:

`expect(true).toBe(false)`

So the unit test can fail whenever it reaches this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I throw errors. I usually do this when I have created new test functions that are not implemented yet.

```
it('should test something when I have implemented it', function() {
    throw new Error('Not implemented yet');
});
```

This lets you use any explanation you want.

Comment: Good idea, I'll accept this once the stackoverflow timer is up.